# simple rails code optimisation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% if defined?(@club.name) && !(@club.name).nil? %>
<%= @club.name %>
<% else %>
clubs:
<% end %>
```

first line looks ugly. any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is your meaning of defined?(@club.name), do you mean @club.respond_to?(:name)  ?

Comment: @pake007: I think the two constructs are equivalent here, though `respond_to` is definitely more common.

Comment: @Matchu: I tried defined?(@club), returned "instance-variable", but defined?(@club.name) returned me nil even if @club.name has value. what's wrong? I am using ruby 1.9.2-p0

Comment: Dunno. In my Ruby 1.9.2, after I defined `class Club; attr_accessor :name; end` and created `club = Club.new`, `defined?(club.name)` returned `"method"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
<% if @club && @club.name %>
  <%= @club.name %>
<% else %>
  clubs:
<% end %>
```

Since `@club` will presumably either be set to a `Club` object or be set to `nil`, we don't really need to explicitly check whether or not the `@club` has a `name` method. Instead, we can just test that `@club` is set at all, and a truthiness test will suffice for that.

Similarly, we don't need an explicit `nil` check on `@club.name`. All values other than `false` and `nil` are considered "truthy," and, since a club's name presumably can't be set to `false`, simply testing its truthiness is equivalent to explicitly checking if it is `nil`.

---

Violet pointed out in the comments that this is actually a fairly common idiom in the Rails world, so a shortcut actually exists. In a Rails environment, all objects, including `nil`, have a method named [`try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try). `try` invokes the method name passed to it as an argument, and either returns that method's return value, or `nil` if that method is not defined.

So, for example:

```
no_name = Club.new
no_name.try(:name) # => nil

so = Club.new :name => 'StackOverflow'
so.try(:name) # => "StackOverflow"

nil.try(:name) # => nil
```

As such, the following is the exact equivalent to the first code block:

```
<% if @club.try(:name) %>
  <%= @club.name %>
<% else %>
  clubs:
<% end %>
```

Much prettier :)

Comment: To add to this, you can avoid doing an "and" statement if you use the "try" method. As in, "if @club.try(:name)"

Comment: @Violet: I like it :) Editing that in now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= @club.name || "clubs:" %>
```

how about that?

Comment: This will throw an error if `@club` is `nil`, which, given the original example, is likely a possibility.

Comment: <%= @club ? @club.name : "clubs:" %>

Comment: @matchu + @mikker both solutions now dont check if on a existing @club object, name is blank or not.

Comment: <%= (@club && !@club.name.blank?) ? @club.name : "clubs:" %> is probably complete. It calls for a helper method in my book or also for more refinement in the @club model.

Comment: @Aditya: both in my answer do, in fact, successfully check for a `nil` name (whether or not it was blank was not a requirement), so I'm a bit confused. I also made a point of not merging them into one line, since `clubs:` to me implied that there was something to follow in that block that the OP hadn't written up yet. If that really is all he's going to output in the negative case, however, then `<%= @club.try(:name) || 'clubs:' %>` would be fantastic :)

Comment: @matchu isnt !(@club.name).nil? effectively !@club.name.blank?. I mean it seems it is checking on the blankness of name attribute of @club? My reading of his requirement didnt find a check on @club instance var in fact. I mean defined?(@club.name) is still not really checking @club is it? Ah the mountains out of molehills! :)

Comment: @Aditya: the difference between `nil?` and `blank?` is that `blank?` checks for an empty string. Since the original code didn't check for the empty string, I didn't, either. And, yeah, checking that `@club` was set was done in a roundabout way: I'm pretty darn sure that's what `defined?(@club.name)` was for, since he was probably getting `NoMethodError`s when `@club` was `nil`, so checking for `@club.name` being defined was the first thing to come to his mind. But I may have over-assumed there.